# Yahoo Finance Download Data

Tags: python, web-scraping, finance

I am trying to scrape finance.yahoo.com and download a data file.  Specifically, this url: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL

I would like to complete two objectives here:

1. I would like to set the data time period parameters to "Max", which I believe I would need to use Selenium and
2. would like to download and save the data file that is embedded in the href that appears when inspect "Download Data".

So far, I am unable to access the drop-down required to click "Max" and also cannot locate the href required to download the file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')

stock = input()
base_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/history?p= 
{}'.format(stock,stock)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(base_url)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("Fl(end) Mt(3px) Cur(p)").click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: please include your current code. There are quite a few Stackoverflow examples of working with Yahoo Finance to help you. We can't help fix your code if we can't see it.

Comment: Sure! I have added my current code - I am working on trying to locate the "Download Data" href so that I can download the data and perform some basic manipulation in pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following shows selectors you can use. I haven't added any wait conditions as the only one needed, in my test runs, I couldn't find; the wait for all new data to be present after pressing apply button. Instead, I use a hard coded time.sleep(5) which should be replaced with a better condition based wait if possible.

```
from selenium import webdriver
# from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL')
try:
    d.find_element_by_css_selector('[name=agree]').click() #oauth
except:
    pass

d.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-icon=CoreArrowDown]').click() #dropdown
d.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-value=MAX]').click() #max
d.find_element_by_css_selector('button.Fl\(start\)').click() # done
d.find_element_by_css_selector('button.Fl\(end\) span').click() #apply
time.sleep(5)
d.find_element_by_css_selector('[download]').click() #download
```

Comment: thanks for showing me how to do this.  I was able to inspect and find the relative xpaths for each of dropdown, max, done, apply and download as well. I was specifically practicing how to use selenium to locate these in an HTML tree. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate #1 right off the bat -- just view the page directly, passing the parameters as requested.

The base URI is: `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history`

The available parameters are: `period1`, `period2`, `interval`, `filter` and `frequency`.

Pretty simple, just grab now as an epoch timestamp, and use it as the `period2` parameter, where `period1` can simply be the beginning epoch `0`. The `interval` and `frequency` can be whatever you want; daily `1d`, weekly `1wk` or monthly `1mo`. Lastly, the `filter` should be `history`.

The completed URI:

`https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=0&period2=1555905600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d`

From there, use Selenium to locate and click the `Download Data` link.

**UPDATE:**

As @QHarr also said, there's numerous questions all over Stack Overflow detailing how to work with Yahoo finance. I also recommend you give [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=yahoo+finance) a whirl.

Comment: Appreciate the response in helping with the first issue.  In response to Selenium, I have used that prior to posting the question, and have included it in my edit - I will include it in any future questions.